# How to upload csv data that can be queried to java application

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I upload a csv file which can be queried to the app enginge datastore ?

Reading this tip :

> Tip: If you have a Java app, you can use the Python appcfg.py tool by
>   installing the Java version of the remote_api handler, which is
>   included with the Java runtime environment. The handler servlet class
>   is com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet.

Copied from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata

I have never used Python. Where is the java version of the remote_api handler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this useful : http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/10/using-the-bulkloader-with-java-app-engine/